# reading line by line from file using shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
   grep "$line" file1.txt
   if [ $status -eq 1]
    echo "$line" >> f2.txt
done < f3.txt
```

When I execute shell script containing above script. I get following error:

```
./test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./test.sh: line 7: `done < f3.txt'
```

Can anyone help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please ask http://www.shellcheck.net/ to find syntax errors before asking here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
   grep "$line" file1.txt
   if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
       echo "$line" >> f2.txt
   fi
done < f3.txt
```

There are a bunch of errors in your code.

1. structure of if is wrong
2. there is a space missing before the closing bracked
3. I believe the $status thing you are using is wrong. You check the return status of a command using $?

Answer (score 2):

Your script can be simplified into this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
   grep -q "$line" file1.txt || echo "$line" >> f2.txt
done < f3.txt
```

Here `echo "$line" >> f2.txt` will execute only when `grep -q` returns non-zero status.